# Let-Form Bind Values In Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I am supposed to reimplement a previously implemented procedure called "Product". I am to use let-form bind values and test it with `(ProductLet 60 40)`. My code is not working properly and I am not sure why.

```
(define (ProductLet a b)
(let ((p a)(q b))
    p q
    (* p q))
  )                  
(ProductLet 60 40)
```

Comment: What are you expecting it to produce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine - well, I'd remove the first two lines with `p` and `q` in the body of the `let`, they're literally doing nothing there:

```
(define (ProductLet a b)
  (let ((p a) (q b))
    (* p q)))

(ProductLet 60 40)
=> 2400
```

Be aware that the body of a `let` is just like the body of a procedure: all the expressions will get executed, but only the value of the last expression will be returned. If you want to, say, display the variables you need to explicitly *print* them, because they won't be returned when the procedure is executed:

```
(define (ProductLet a b)
  (let ((p a) (q b))
    (displayln p)
    (displayln q)
    (* p q)))

(ProductLet 60 40)
60
40
2400
```